# QGIS 2.18 on OS X fewer functionality than Windows version

Tags: qgis

Is there a reason why the OS X version of QGIS 2.18 has way less functionality than the QGIS 2.18 Windows version?
Looking at the `dissolve` for example. On Windows I can dissolve on more than one field. That option does not even show up on OS X. Same for `Join Attributes by location`. On a windows machine I can specify parameters such as "Intersect", "Overlap", etc. On OS X there are no such parameters.

Comment: Have you also installed the _dependency framework (GDAL Complete)_ as mentioned in the Mac OS X section of the [download page for QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)?

Comment: @PhilG of course!

Comment: Just checking - know plenty of people who've missed that part initially.

Comment: @PhilG Wouldnt the installation of QGIS itself fail? Or wouldnt QGIS crash on startup of the App?

Comment: Good point - I suppose it would.